# How to set full-pixel anti-aliasing in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, fonts, rendering, anti-aliasing

Is it possible to change the web pages font rendering method in Firefox on Windows to something
other than sub-pixel?
**I want normal full-pixel** antialiasing instead of sub-pixel, but I can't find an option.

What I have tried first is to change this parameter in `about:config` list

```
gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode
```

I've tried values from -1 to 5 but it still renders sub-pixel anti-aliasing. There are
some changes to the looks, like letter spacing and contrast,  but it does not do full-pixel, so the fonts still stay sub-pixel antialiased.
I was restarting Firefox after each change to make sure it applies my changes.

So had no luck here.

Also I tried to remove all font names from this field, just to make sure there is no exceptions.

```
gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.force_gdi_classic_for_families
```

Unfortunately this did not make any difference.

Any suggestions how to achieve what I want?

Comment: [Documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_%3A_FAQs_%3A_About%3Aconfig_Entries#Config.) with futher details about **about:config entries**.